# Get prediction confidence through Decision Tree Regression in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas, confidence-interval

Is there a way I can attach some sort of confidence with my predictions from Decision Tree Regression output in python?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0, criterion="mae")
dt_fit = dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = dt_fit.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I think you might have a better chance of getting a response by adding an sklearn tag to your question. People providing answers also frequently would like to see a little code, perhaps the code that you're using now to generate your predictions.

Answer (score 0):

df_fit.predict_prob() is for classification problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [`dt_fit.predict_proba(X_test)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba)